# How to tell jenkins to build the the entity metamodel?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jpa-2.0

I have two project, both on jenkins:

1. Project A, a common project used as a dependency by several project, including Project B. Project A contains only JPA Entity Class with EclipseLink Provider
2. Project B is a JSF 2.2 Web Interface, using Project A as a dependency. I use CriteraBuilder to create query and so, I have to use the generated metamodel classes (the famous MyEntity_.class stuff).

My local Netbeans workspace works just fine, my CriteraBuilder is ok. But when Jenkins try to compile Project B, It says "unknown symbol" about a generated metamodel class. Project A compiles just fine with Jenkins.

So I guess Jenkins does not generate the metamodel classes. How can I tell it to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: I use maven on both local workspace and Jenkins. Unfortunately, I can't access the jenkins configuration since I don't have the rights... Also, jenkins builds are deployed on Nexus

Comment: You use a maven project (probably, you tagged maven the question) ? The maven build works on local machine ? Jenkins build configuration do the same maven build with same goals ? Agent have same maven configuration ? Probably not, because the maven build should work everywhere with same configuration. Please add more information about your build configuration

Comment: I edit my question. But I guess Jenkins use the default goals `clean install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maven goals configuration of jenkins wasn't right. After correction, every things was fine.